# What should I put in requirements file for pip to pick the correct git branch?

Tags: python, git, github, pip

I have seen the -e option which I can use to ask pip to download specific packages from github. However it seems to download the master branch. Is there a way to pick up another branch?

Comment: Does this syntax still work? `pip install git+git_repo_url@branch#egg=eggname`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find documentation of requirements file here: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/logic.html#git

```
-e git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git@master#egg=MyProject
```